# Search bar remove text is not working in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working with search bar in xamarin forms. I am not able to remove search text in search bar by clicking cross button. I am using custom renderer for remove cancel text in search bar. When I am using that renderer I am not able delete the text, If I remove that renderer it work's fine. what the wrong I have done in renderer file. Here is the sample code in renderer for hide the cancel button beside the search bar.

Renderer Sample code:

```
  protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChnagedEventArgs e)
  {

      Control.ShowCancelButton = false;
  }
```

[image]

When I try to remove text in search bar by clicking cross image in search bar it's not working in xamarin ios but it's working fine in ios.

Sample code :

```
 <StackLayout Grid.Column = "0" Orientation = "Horizontal">
 <Image Source = "backarrow.png" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "CenterAndExpand" />                           
 <controls:CustomSearchbar x:Name = "CustomSearchbar" BackgroundColor ="Transparent" Text ="{Binding SearchTag}" SearchCommand ="{Binding RestaurantSearchCommand}" GHorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "CenterAndExpand" >
```

Here is the code I am using for search bar. Here 'customsearchbar' class is inherited from searchrenderer.

Comment: Could you share either your code our XAML you're using to call the searchbar?

Comment: Hi cvanbeek, I am adding sample code what I am using.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. It works fine with your code(there's some spelling errors) on my side. I post my code for you. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me.

Here's my code for example:

**MySearchBar.cs in PCL:**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Kevin_XF
{
    public class MySearchBar : SearchBar
    {

    }
}
```

**MySearchBarRenderer.cs in iOS platform:**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Kevin_XF.iOS;
using Kevin_XF;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MySearchBar),typeof(MySearchBarRenderer))]
namespace Kevin_XF.iOS
{
    public class MySearchBarRenderer: SearchBarRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.ShowsCancelButton = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml code in MainPage.xaml:**

```
<StackLayout>
        <local:MySearchBar x:Name = "CustomSearchbar" BackgroundColor ="Transparent" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "CenterAndExpand"  />
</StackLayout>
```

**It works like this:**

[image]

Comment: @Deepak, did my answer help you?